# How to create FormGroup programmaticly and collect those values in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-directive

I have to create new object with data collected from my FormBuilder. Main issue is that ***inputs*** are being created via *ngFor directive which means, that sometimes there will be two, three, four or even more of those.

```
    <form [formGroup]="formType"
    (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div 
      <div>
        <button >Select column type</button>
        <div>
          <button *ngFor="let col of sessionService.schedulerConfig.columns" (click)="selectColumnType(col.type, col)" ngbDropdownItem>{{col.text}}</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div *ngFor="let value of inputsForColumnValues">
        <label>Current {{value}}:</label> 
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="{{value}}">
      </div>
      Special values:
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

and my .ts below

```
export class AddingColumnsComponent implements OnInit {
  
  schedulerConfig: any = schedulerConfig;
  scheduler: Scheduler;
  formType: FormGroup;
  inputsForColumnValues: any[];

  constructor(
    private formbuilder: FormBuilder,
    private sessionService: SessionService,
    ) 
    { 
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formType = this.formbuilder.group({
      valueInput: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }

  selectColumnType(type, column){
    this.formType.value.columnType = type;
    this.inputsForColumnValues = Object.values(column);
  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.formType.value)
  }
}
```

selectColumnType function (included in button) determines how many inputs will be displayed. Then, below there is a div with *ngFor directive, which "prints" required amount of inputs. My question is, how to create [formControlName] programmaticly. If possible, how to isolate every single value.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide some code for us (mainly the .ts)

Comment: sure, sorry :) Edited

Comment: based on your description it sounds like you are looking to use reactive forms, to be able to dynamically add new form controls, and reference them in the template. I would suggest viewing the official documents on [ReactiveForms & DynamicForms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms). as it provides the steps for what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

This approach:

```
this.formType.value.columnType = type;
```

is completely wrong, you are not pushing any form controls to the FormGroup.

So here is a sample on how to dynamically add FormControls to your form. You can adjust the correct values if this is not how you intended to display them like this. But you get the idea :)

So the selectColumnType is where you would want to push new formcontrols to your form, you can do that by calling [`addControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl), which takes the name of the formcontrol and any initial value you might have, otherwise empty string (in this case):

```ts
selectColumnType(type, column) {
  this.formType.addControl(type, this.formbuilder.control(""));
}
```

Now we are properly adding controls to the form :)

In the template you could use the [`keyvalue`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe to iterate through the formgroup object:

```html
<div *ngFor="let value of formType.controls | keyvalue">
  <label>Current {{ value.key }}:</label>
  <input class="form-control" [formControlName]="value.key" [placeholder]="value.key">
</div>
```

And that's it, now you should get a nice object from the form.